# Make inactive windows transparent in Kubuntu/Compiz

Tags: kde, window-manager, kubuntu, compiz

In Kubuntu, I would like to make windows transparent/translucent when they are inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer, For Kubuntu 12.04:

- Go to "System Settings" > Desktop Effects > All effects (tab) >
- Search for "Translucency"
- Turn this plugin on, and configure it
- Set the "inactive windows" setting somewhere in the middle (to your liking)
- click OK
- click Apply

This does not seem to work when an application has multiple windows :(

Comment: what if I want to make active window transparent

Comment: @Anwar, I am not currently using Kubuntu.  It sounds like a separate question, though--I suggest you post your own question.  Hope that helps!